# Docker overlay занимает всю память

Tags: postgresql, docker

Docker оверлеи жрут очень много памяти и спустя время её просто не хватает, что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно удалить неиспользуемые образы и контейнеры.

Comment: еще разные варианты `purge` есть

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте удалить неиспользуемые образы,и остановленные контейнеры командой

`docker system prune -a`

Так же место может занимать то, что находится в ваших контейнерах. Возможно это сами базы данных postgresql